# Calling Function in js by storing function name in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have one function named root and at next part I am storing function name in variable (call) . I want to call function by using variable name For Example:-

(note:- not using root() using variable call's value )

```
 call = "root";

 root = function() {
    name = "This is My root function";
    console.log(name)
 }
```

Can we call root function by value of variable (call) Is it possible.

Comment: While this is possible I strongly suggest you consider your design. Do you absolutely NEED the variable to contain the function name? Javascript variables can point to the function itself: `call = root` instead of `call = "root"`. If all you need is to implement some sort of function calling logic then use function references instead of function names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming call is a global browser variable, you can do:

```
window[call]();
```

Answer (score 2):

[`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) is probably what you need, but use with caution.

Comment: Don't do this ─ use the answer by @jim-cote.

Comment: @jhpratt Please put your explanation along with `"Don't do this"`.